# What does this error ((#12) singular published story API is deprecated for versions v2.4 and higher) means?

Tags: node.js, facebook, messenger

I'm building a Facebook Messenger Bot. I'm using this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fb-messenger

And when I requests new users' profile I get the following error:

```
{ message: '(#12) singular published story API is deprecated for versions v2.4 and higher',
type: 'OAuthException',
code: 12,
fbtrace_id: 'EX7RiQ+ee26' }
```

It works with all admins, and 200+ testers we have (Our app is not yet approved) but new testers and even Facebook's Bot reviewers give me this error when I try to get their profile.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.